# jQuery to extract correct values from DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Kendo UI for File Upload.  I want to then get the correct properties from the DOM tree.

On my cshtml I have:

```
<input name="target" id="target" type="file" />
```

I then want to get the value of each file - so I am doing the following in my js:

```
  $('input[name="target"]').each(function () {
        console.log($('input[name="target"]'));
        // get the value of each file - do something with value if set - not if blank
   });
```

In the console I am seeing the below - two inputs one with a #target and one without - not sure why:

[image]

If I expand the 0: input element I get the following so in this case the input value has a value:

> value: "C:\fakepath\MyDoc.txt"

Expanding the 1: input#target and scrolling down to the value it is blank as "".

In my .each(function how can I extract the value of each of these inputs so in pesudo code I want to do something like:

```
foreach (input in (input[name="target"])
{
   if (input.val() != "")
   {
       alert("Value Found");
       alert(input.val();
   }
   else
   {
       alert("No Value Found");
   }
}
```

Doing what Brian said and a console.log(this) on inside my $.each... gives:

```
    <input name="target" type="file" data-role="upload" multiple="multiple" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">

<input name="target" id="target" type="file" data-role="upload" multiple="multiple" autocomplete="off">
```

So this pulls out both of the individual inputs that are there but neither contains the value attribute which in one case will be the file "C:\Desktop\MyDoc.txt" and the other value would be blank ""

Comment: Define "value for each file."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - so the value is the name of the file - using kendo uploader for multiple files when uploading a single file a second input is added and the value is blank "" - i.e no file is there for this.  The first input has the filename that was added - i.e C:\Desktop\MyFile.txt

Comment: @Brian - Thanks - it looked correct on my Preview :\

Comment: Why not `console.log(this);` instead of another selector, you've already retrieved a collection, during the each loop: `this` is each index of that collection

Comment: Do you have form with multiple selects? This example creates another `<input name='the same one'>` on file selection. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/index

Comment: @Cheery no dont have multpile selects - I am using the same code from the example link you have posted.  If you add a single file to that it seems to then create two inputs - one with the filename which has a value and the second is blank

Comment: @Brian - I will change and do a console.log(this) and see what I get out of it

Comment: This is exactly how example by link is working. In your case, too, you have one input with selected file MyDoc.txt and the second one is empty.

Comment: If there is only one input then drop the each loop `console.log($('input[name="target"]'));`

Comment: @Brian - there is two inputs though - question updated with the result from doing a console.log(this); which pulls out both of the inputs however neither have the value

Comment: @Cheery - yes is there anyway to get the value from the input with selected file and ignore the empty one?

Comment: You said that second one is empty, so just ignore it. `$('input[name="target"][value!=""]')` or check value in `.each` loop.

Comment: is within a change event? if not the loop is running while the input is empty

Comment: @Brian - no I have this in the submit form function - if you click the kendo link Cheery posted that is the same code I am using. Perhaps I dont need the $.each loop to do what I need a alert the value for the scenario when it is there and alert 'no value' for the input that doesnt have a value?

Comment: @Brian using  console.log($(this).val()); in my each works - you can put that as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` within your `each` callbacks instead of a jQuery selector

Retrieve `this` value with `$(this).val();`

For more information regarding `this` read the documentation regarding `this`  and the object method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)

```
$('input[name="target"]').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).val()); // 'this' is each iteration of the each loop
});
```